# Ember.js - controlling embedded/aggregate model creation

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

See [sample on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/harlan/7Hgw2/1/).

With Ember.js, is there a way to control model creation from JSON, in particular creation of embedded/aggreates? In example below, would like Person model to contain instances of Friend. In Knockout this is accomplished through the mapping plugin. Would appreciate any suggestions.

```
Person = Ember.Object.extend({
    numberOfFriends : function() {
        return this.get("friends").length;
    }.property("friends"),
});

Friend = Ember.Object.extend({
    isAvailable : function() {
        var stat = this.get('status');
        return stat == 'online'; 
    }.property('status'),
});

var personData = {
    name : "Fozzie Bear",
    friends : [ 
        {
            name : "Kermit The Frog",
            status : "online"
        },
        {
            name : "Miss Piggy",
            status : "sleeping"
        }
    ]
};

var person = Person.create(personData);
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure, but I think you can use [ember-data](https://github.com/emberjs/data)

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please try and elaborate what you are trying to do.

Comment: Rajat - Attempting to create an Ember model instance from JSON where the top level model (Person) has an association to another model we defined (Friend). Did you have a look at the sample on JSFiddle, that should help?

Comment: Thanks MilkyWay and Aski, will attempt with ember-data and follow up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should indeed use [ember-data](https://github.com/emberjs/data).